# Select same account numbers in a new table

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

Using Teradata SQL Assistant, I want to be able to pull a table a year ahead but only the ones that would match the results in the query from the year before. Here's what I am trying to do. I pulled a table that contains information where the results in a specific column equals 0 for no. I want to pull information from 1 year ahead where the results in that column equals 1 but only include the account numbers that came when I pulled the results for the year before. Like only pull the customer account numbers for the year ahead that are the same from the year before.

Explanation: I pull the one table that has 0 in the column. From that, I want to see which of those accounts became a 1 in the table from a year ahead. The table has millions of accounts and I just have my settings for 10,000 of them so I want to see of those 10,000 in the first year that did not have the product, how many of them became 1 in the second year.

Can I do this? If so, how? I have been googling and I do not think I am explaining what I am trying to do correctly in my google query so I am coming up short with results.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help other people make sense of what you want to do.

Comment: I would be unable to provide the data. It is a very very large data set. What I am trying to see is the change from a customer not having a product a year ago, which would be marked as 0 in a column to see how many of those customer's ended up obtaining the product a year later which would be marked with a 1. Is that more of an explanation or still too vague? Thank you for responding.

Comment: So I want the data from one table that has customer's marked as 0 for not having the product. And then on the customer data from a year ahead I want those same customer's from the first pull only if they are marked 1 for the product.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for clarifying. That makes it a little simpler. I would put the second year data in a subquery and filter the main table on the first year and quantity = 0. This will give you two columns one with the first year and one with the second year. If you're only looking for this information for a single product_id you will need to add this to both `WHERE` clauses.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME.ACCOUNT_ID, TABLE_NAME.QUANTITY AS "2019" , YEAR_TWO.QUANTITY AS "2020"
FROM TABLE_NAME
LEFT JOIN 
          (
            SELECT *
            FROM TABLE 
            WHERE YEAR = 2020
          ) YEAR_TWO ON TABLE_NAME.ACCOUNT_ID = YEAR_TWO.ACCOUNT_ID
WHERE TABLE_NAME.YEAR = 2019
AND TABLE_NAME.QUANTITY = 0
```

If you want just the % of accounts that are no longer 0 in the second year you could try something like this (adding up all the 1s and dividing by total count)

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME.YEAR,  SUM(YEAR_TWO.QUANTITY) / COUNT(YEAR_TWO.QUANTITY) AS PERCENTAGE_NOT_ZERO
FROM TABLE_NAME
LEFT JOIN 
          (
            SELECT *
            FROM TABLE 
            WHERE YEAR = 2020
          ) YEAR_TWO ON TABLE_NAME.ACCOUNT_ID = YEAR_TWO.ACCOUNT_ID
WHERE TABLE_NAME.YEAR = 2019
AND TABLE_NAME.QUANTITY = 0
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME.YEAR
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I added comments to my original post because I think it's still not explaining what I was trying to accomplish. I pull the one table that has 0 in the column. From that, I want to see which of those accounts became a 1 in the table from a year ahead. The table has millions of accounts and I just have my settings for 10,000 of them so I want to see of those 10,000 in the first year that did not have the product, how many of them became 1 in the second year.

Comment: Seems like you may want an INNER JOIN between the two subqueries instead of LEFT JOIN.

Comment: An INNER JOIN would exclude all the rows that have a 0 in both 2019 and 2020.  I think he still wants to include those in order to see the portion that didn't change as well as the portion that did change. (he would need both in order to get the proportion that did change) InvisibleInk please correct me if I'm wrong.